Make a created class variable reachable anywhere
So I am very new to C# and I am trying to reach a Class variable that was created inside of a case loop.
But it keep saying that the class variable doesn't exist.
Is there a way to make it public so that everything inside of the Class can reach the Class Variable?
Here is the example from my code.
string input = Console.ReadLine();
switch (input)
{
     case "1":
         Account personalAccount = new Account(userName);
         personalAccount.createAccount();
         Console.WriteLine($"Welcome! {userName} Your balance is {personalAccount.balance}");
     break;

{
     case "2":
         Console.WriteLine($Your balance is {personalAccount.balance}");
     break;
}

I am trying to access the Class variable that was created inside of case "1", from case "2".
I tried to create the variable in the beginning of the program, and then just fill it in when it was time to create the Class Variable.
I also tried googling, but it was hard to show the difference between Class and Class Variable, hopefully this code snipped helped making sense of my sistuation.

First of all, your syntax is off, ie this { before case "2" is not allowed. Second, It just makes no sense to access a variable created in one case in another case, because, once case "1" has been selected, your code will never enter case "2" (at least in the same run). Consider what happens, when the user inputs "2" before "1" how would that work then?

This was just an example of what I wanted to try to do, and not my code.
It is much easier to explain like this than to post a big snippet of my actual code.

The problem with over-simplification is, that it often loses some important context and leads people reading this question int wrong directions ...

Your code (and the answer below) requires that case "1" has run before case "2" to get a  non-null value, looks very fragile to me.

Suggested reading: Scope of Variables in C#  also Basic Concepts - Declarations in C#

Visibility of variable is limited to scope.
In your case the scope is the case block, only this one. So the variable is available only there.
In order to access this variable from other scope (the other case) you need to define it in some enclosing scope, for example just before switch:
string input = Console.ReadLine();
Account personalAccount = null;
switch (input)
{
    case "1":
         personalAccount = new Account(userName);
         // ...
         break;
    case "2":
         Console.WriteLine($"Your balance is {personalAccount?.balance}"); // Don't forget to check if personalAccount is null!
         // ...
         break;
    //...
}


Thank you so much! This was just what I was looking for!
I had tried to create it outside the case block, but I didn't try to assign it a value of null!

This code will always return null since C# switch can't 'fall through'.
